# Evaluate $I(a,0)$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

Let $I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}x^a(1-x)^bdx$, where $a \geq 1, b \geq 1$ and $a, b$ are integers. If $b=0$ and $(1-x)^0=1$ (this is to confirm the property $x^0=1$) for x in $[0,1]$, then what is $I(a,0)$? I went through the entire process and subbed $b=0$ and got $\int_{0}^{1}x^adx$, where upon evaluation I got $\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}|_{0}^{1}$ which is $\frac{1}{a+1}$. Did I do it right?

Comment: Yes, you got it right